# variable width index oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, indexing

using oracle 11g.

I'm looking for a feature which will allow me to define an index with variable width which depends on the occurrence rate of a given value. this is for non unique indexes with range scans.

i.e.

table T is

column J,column K, column L, ...

index I is

non-unique index on T (J (, - if more than 1% -   K (, - if more than 10% -   L ) ))

this way the index will be narrow for values with low occurrence rate (long tail) and wider for values with high occurrence rate.

now when i select from the table using (J,K,L) it will use the index and get a narrow pretty much ordered result set always.

any ideas? does such a thing exist?
i thought of partitioning but it might be cumbersome.

P.S. will also be OK with fixed numbers instead of percentages.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're hoping to accomplish.  An index needs to have a fixed number of columns.  You could potentially create a function-based index that sometimes stores the values and sometimes stores a `NULL` but it's not obvious that this would actually save you a meaningful amount of space in the index.  I'm also unclear what "if more than 1%" and "if more than 10%" means in this context.

Comment: yes.
i'm looking for a way to have an index with non-fixed number of columns. 

in the example, what i meant is that rows with given value of J, which appear more than 1% of the table size, will be further indexed by the K column, and rows with given J and K which appear more than 10% of the table size, will be further indexed by the L column.

this can serve two purposes at once: keeping the index width small on average (good for inserts), get a good selectivity for certain values (in this cases oracle usually does variable peeking and resort to full table scan).

Comment: You can't have an index with a variable number of columns.  Assuming J is non-NULL, you'd still have an index entry for every row in the table so you wouldn't have a dramatically smaller index unless K and L are particularly large columns.  Index size is not obviously relevant to the speed of `INSERT` operations.  Plus, unless you're going to define up front what values are popular, you'd also spend ridiculous amounts of time during `INSERT` operations determining whether the newly inserted tuple is common, potentially forcing previously inserted rows to be indexed differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an index with a variable number of columns that depends on the data for the very simple reason that updating the index would be a performance nightmare.

Every time you inserted, deleted, or updated a value in the index, the database would have to figure out whether the key in the index would need to be expanded or contracted.  This could require, essentially, a full table scan for what should be a fast operation.

What is the problem with having all three columns in the index?  Let the database engine worry about the particular structure.

If some of the variables are long (say long strings), then think about a functional index that uses only the first n-characters for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

[Index key compression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5012.htm#SQLRF53999) can significantly reduce the size and improve performance on indexes with repetitive values.  Put the least selective columns first to see the largest benefit.

```
create index t_idx on t(l, k, j) compress;
```